# What are the proper type annotations for an awaited fetch() call in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I'm trying to convert a small existing JavaScript codebase to TypeScript, and in my efforts to write type annotations for every function I'm fighting with one that returns from an `await fetch` call.

Visual Studio is yelling at me when I try some reasonable choices - Firefox gives me a `Response` object when I run something simple (like `await fetch('google.com');`) in the console, so I tried some variations of Response or Promise but VS gives me the following error: "[Type] is not a valid async function return type because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value." I'm at my wits end here.

Here's the function in question:

```
const updateLinkCount = async (id: string) /* : What type? */ => await fetch(uri, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Return_value

Comment: Fetch definitions are in TypeScript 2.2 in lib.dom.d.ts

Comment: `Promise<any>` should work at least.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov Unfortunately it doesn't - see my response to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

it returns the same that fetch function returns, because after the "=>" return keyword is hidden. So, it's a Promise.

Comment: When I defined the function as `Promise<any>`, I get the following error: "An async function or method requires the 'Promise' constructor."

Comment: @slondr in your tsconfig add this: ```"lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],```